# Disable Dropbox Camera Upload for a particular device

Tags: macos, dropbox, import

Is there a way to disable the Dropbox auto-import for a particular device on OSX?

I want it to automatically import pictures from my phone, but not from my camera.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no options to except a particular device from auto importing photos into DropBox. You either toggle auto import of photos on or off which effects all devices. The closest solution would be to write an AppleScript to differentiate between your phone and your camera, and allow only your phone to auto import photos into your DropBox.

Comment: I guess one more reason to uninstall dropbox then.

Comment: Does it not have a "prompt me every time" option in OSX?